# If a hobgoblin is charmed using a Rod of Rulership and given commands that go against the orders of its normal leader, what happens?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, monsters, charmed

The description of the [*Rod of Rulership*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/rod-of-rulership) says:

> You can use an action to present the rod and command obedience from each creature of your choice that you can see within 120 feet of you. Each target must succeed on a DC 15 Wisdom saving throw or be charmed by you for 8 hours. While charmed in this way, the creature regards you as its trusted leader. If harmed by you or your companions, or commanded to do something contrary to its nature, a target ceases to be charmed in this way.

The description of the [Charmed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Charmed) condition states:

> - A charmed creature can’t attack the charmer or target the charmer with harmful abilities or magical effects.
> - The charmer has advantage on any ability check to interact socially with the creature.

Per the "Military Might" section in the description of [hobgoblins](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/monsters-h#Hobgoblins) in the MM, hobgoblins are used to following the chain of command:

> In their martial society, every hobgoblin has a rank, from the powerful leaders and champions, to the rank-and-file foot soldiers (...)

Assume the player characters have successfully charmed a tribe of Hobgoblins by presenting and activating the *Rod*, but the hobgoblins' leader succeeds on the save and is not charmed.

What happens if the characters demand obedience from these Hobgoblins (e.g. commanding the hobgoblins to follow them), but their leader objects?

Comment: I'm voting to close, "what would X alignment do" falls into the "opinion based"
 category of alignment questions, see this meta for more discussion: [Are questions about alignment on topic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5357) This seems like a good question for [chat].

Comment: With regrets, I'm voting to close. As discussed in [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5357/43484), alignment is a difficult topic, and most questions about what actions correspond to what alignments are too rooted in opinion to be answered by RPG.SE.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Dang it, pardner, you're quick on the draw.

Comment: How if I reformulate and remove the alignment part? Question is still if the Charm overrides the established leadership struture?

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin That's probably *prima facie* on-topic, but read through this meta discussion first: [Does "Ask the DM / GM" equate to "Primarily opinion based?"](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7353)

Comment: I think this form of the question is probably fine.

Comment: I voted to close as well, not every hobgoblin is the same, and as with all NPC's they do 'whatever the DM decides is best for the plot'. How would an NPC react is almost always going to be opinion based unfortunately.

Comment: @SeriousBri Have a read through the meta I linked above. I think this is one of those “wait and see if it generates low quality answers” situations.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### It's up to the DM.

Ultimately, the DM controls the NPCs, but we can give an examination of the factors at play here to provide some guidance for how a DM might rule on this situation. Consider the effect of the Rod of Rulership:

> While charmed in this way, the creature regards you as its trusted leader.

So you now have a group of hobgoblins that regard you as their trusted leader. However, *the rod does not say that you supplant any trusted leaders they already have*. To me, it seems like now the hobgoblins have *two* trusted leaders, and how they respond to the conflicting commands from those leaders is up to the DM.

Comment: "To me, it seems like now the hobgoblins have two trusted leaders, and how they respond to the conflicting commands from those leaders is up to the DM." I like this idea.  Particularly I see them flipping back and forth between the latest order given by either. "Bring me that barrel."  "Put down that barrel."  "I need that barrel, bring it to me."  "Why do you have that barrel again? I said put it down."