# How does Rod of Rulership work?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, charmed

Our group are the proud owners of a [rod of rulership](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4747-rod-of-rulership) that we pried out of the dead coils of a defeated Spirit Naga. We since have successfully employed this device in a couple of large encounters with lots of minions.

Our DM is fond of springing monster-ball encounters on us: all the monsters of a given faction ambush us at the same time. These encounters are up to 10 times the XP value of a "deadly" encounter, and include lots of opponents. The rod has proven helpful to not only survive these, but give us a fighting chance.

Our DM is not happy with this outcome. They have made rulings to nerf the effect, arguing that the effect makes fights "too easy" and the rod states creatures cannot be commanded to do something contrary to their nature. This is of course their right to call. At the same time, they like to play RAW. So we are trying to understand what is and is not within RAW for the Rod:

1. You have to present a convincing narrative on why you should be their leader to the targets when presenting the rod (similar to what *suggestion* demands)
2. Attacking any member of the opposing group will break the charm on those that are charmed
3. Ordering charmed targets to attack their former allies will break the charm
4. Commanding hostile, agressive creatures not to attack your companions will break the charm
5. You cannot charm creatures with the rod when already in combat or direct conflict

I'm in particular interested in this last one -- as I read the item, the earliest point at which the charm could be broken is when you issue a command that goes against the charmed creature's nature.

We already resolved if it is possible to command targets against commands of an uncharmed leader they report to as [up to DM ruling](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/195840/if-a-hobgoblin-is-charmed-using-a-rod-of-rulership-and-given-commands-that-go-ag).

**I would appreciate answers that cover the individual unresolved points explicitly**, with the rationale for why it should or should not be possible to do each one.

I'm grateful and appreciate the recommendations to work with the DM on how we'd like to play, but still would be interested in the actual question about how Rod of Rulership works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing here is that, when it comes to interpreting how the *rod of rulership* works according to RAW, there aren't very many written rules to interpret. The only relevant text is the description of the rod itself, and the effect of the charmed condition. In their entirety, these are:

> You can use an action to present the rod and command obedience from each creature of your choice that you can see within 120 feet of you. Each target must succeed on a DC 15 Wisdom saving throw or be charmed by you for 8 hours. While charmed in this way, the creature regards you as its trusted leader. If harmed by you or your companions, or commanded to do something contrary to its nature, a target ceases to be charmed in this way. The rod can't be used again until the next dawn.

> - A charmed creature can't attack the charmer or target the charmer with harmful abilities or magical effects.
> - The charmer has advantage on any ability check to interact socially with the creature.

So, with these rules in mind, let's address your questions.

> 1. You have to present a convincing narrative on why you should be their leader to the targets when presenting the rod (similar to what suggestion demands)

There is no RAW support for this. As written, you simply invoke the rod's power, and anyone who fails their save now treats you as their trusted leader. No mention is made of any requirement to justify your leadership to those affected. (In fact, such may not even be possible; the rod works on creatures that do not understand any language at all, and on creatures that share no language in common with you.)

That's not to say that the affected creatures will follow your orders unquestioningly, however; while charmed they trust you and will respect you as an authority, but if you give them orders that seem dangerous or nonsensical in context, you might need to justify those orders to them, or they might try and do what they think you meant rather than what you actually said. This should vary between creatures; quarrelsome academics, for instance, would seem much more prone to question their orders than disciplined soldiers, who are trained to do what they're told even if they don't understand why.

Remember that while a creature is charmed you have advantage on social interactions with them, so it will be easier to persuade, deceive or intimidate them into doing what you want them to do.

> 2. Attacking any member of the opposing group will break the charm on those that are charmed

This also doesn't have RAW support. From the rod's description, emphasis mine:

> If harmed by you or your companions, [...] **a target** ceases to be charmed in this way.

The rod's effect applies to many individual creatures, not the concept of a group of creatures. If *a creature* is affected and you harm *that creature*, the charm effect ends for *that creature*. The text does not mention harming the creature's allies as a condition that will end the charm, whether those allies are also charmed or not.

An affected creature may be very confused if you attack other creatures they regard as their friends and allies, though. They trust you, but if someone you trusted suddenly attacks your friend, you wouldn't just sit passively and let it happen. They might try to interpose themselves to prevent you hurting their friend, try and calm you down or otherwise interfere with the attacks, though they cannot attack you directly due to the charm.

The point at which the charm might break is if you order them not to defend their ally - then it is the DM's judgement call as to whether or not it would go against their nature to follow that order. Again, this is behaviour that will vary between creatures; a coward would probably find that command within their nature, but a brave and honourable sort probably would not.

> 3. Ordering charmed targets to attack their former allies will break the charm

This is not explicitly a condition that breaks the charm as described by the rod, and ultimately comes down to DM ruling on whether or not attacking their (former) allies would be "against their nature". For an enemy already predisposed to fractious infighting - say, a group of poorly disciplined bandits - it's easy to argue that a bunch of them switching allegiance to support a new leader they like better, and turning on those who still support the old, is entirely within their nature. Conversely, for a group of honourable knights, the idea of turning their weapons on their comrades-in-arms may be utterly abhorrent.

But don't forget you also have advantage on checks to persuade and deceive the charmed creatures; you might be able to convince them that the others are traitors who are about to betray them and they need to fight back! If the honourable knight honestly believes they've been betrayed by their former ally, their compunctions about fighting them are probably less of an issue.

DM adjudication is required here, but the fact remains that attacking a former ally is not *inherently* a charm-breaking condition; it depends on the nature of the creatures and the circumstances.

> 4. Commanding hostile, aggressive creatures not to attack your companions will break the charm

Again this is not RAW and is a question of whether or not such restraint is against the creature's nature. For some creatures, the idea of *not* attacking an enemy could well be against their nature; one imagines many kinds of demons, for instance, would never be able to restrain themselves in that way. But this doesn't seem like it should be true for most intelligent creatures, who are capable of obeying an order from a trusted leader to stop fighting, or even to surrender entirely. If a disciplined soldier hears their commander order them to stand down, then they'll stop; especially if their enemies are also stopping (since otherwise they will break the charm by harming the creature anyway!). They might Ready an action to attack anyway in the event that hostilities continue, of course - they're not magically compelled to follow your orders to the letter, just to treat you as an authority.

> 5. You cannot charm creatures with the rod when already in combat or direct conflict

This is not RAW by any means. The rod's text and the charmed condition simply include no such limitations. Some charm effects may not work on creatures who are already hostile; some charm effects are saved against with advantage if you're already fighting the creature. This is always specified in those effects, though, and is not a general rule. The rod works on any creature regardless of how it originally felt about you and whether or not you are in combat with it.

Comment: +1, this kind of evaluation/analysis is what I'm looking for

Comment: Note I reordered the question (pulled out 5. from the list as already resolved), maybe you want to adjust the numbering to match.

Answer (score 2):

Given how many creatures the Rod can potentially influence, there's very little text describing the interaction between the opposing parties, so there's bound to be a lot up to DM ruling. As a DM, I would probably use the Rod mechanic as a sort of "*Mass Charm Person*" spell, where the relevant part of "*Charm Person*", to me, is (emphasis mine):

> [...] It must make a Wisdom saving throw, and does so **with advantage if you or your     companions are fighting it**.

So, wander into a small hamlet and present the rod to the indifferent villagers? Wisdom saving throw as usual. Try to dissuade the ferocious orks from murdering you? OK, but they do get advantage on the saving throw.

The "contrary to its nature" clause is a bit tricky, because that's natural language, not Game Language. A Demon's nature in 5e is Chaotic Evil, so commanding it to do lawful good would be basically impossible. I would also fall back on *Suggestion*'s wording here:

> The suggestion must be worded in such a manner as to make the course of action sound reasonable. Asking the creature to stab itself, throw itself onto a spear, immolate itself, or do some other obviously harmful act ends the spell.

That being said, it is up to the DM imo.

Answer (score 2):

#### Your GM is letting you off easy....

...at least part of the time.

There are a couple of the features of the rod that help limit its significant power. It requires attunement, but also

- Once a day
- For 8 hours

Of course, by default the game is tuned to more than one encounter a day. As the DMG says:

> Assuming typical adventuring conditions and average luck, most adventuring parties can handle about six to eight medium or hard encounters in a day.

My eyes cross when I go through the encounter math, and while I know there are GMs who do it by the math, I don't do it that way and I don't know any GMs who do, but you don't have to do the math to know that if every day is a single deadly encounter, then you always know you can safely use your once-a-day item.

On the other hand, if there are multiple encounters, then you have to decide when you use your once-a-day toy. The rest of the day, you've got to lug this thing around, soaking up an attunement slot.

Of course, throwing a small encounter also let's you try to suborn a small group of monsters, and then use them against the monsters later. Personally, I think that sounds like a lot of fun.

And then there's the 8 hour limitation.  Again, you use the rod right after breakfast on a buncha mokes, long around tea time they're going to turn on you.

#### Working it out with the GM

You're on the right track, working it out with the GM.

And the GM's on the right track, working with you to define how a powerful magic item works in the game that makes it fun for everyone.

I get why your GM says it makes the encounters "too easy". I don't think it's that they're playing GM vs. Player, I think it's because this single item is really turning encounters around.

Above I talked a bit about changing encounters, but it's also pretty reasonable to customize an item, particularly a powerful one, so that it fits the game. If you don't like the GM's nerfs, suggest your own.  Things like 1 out of 6 times, it actually backfires, might give the GM something to work with, without nerfing the abilities it already has.

Please pass this along to your GM: don't read it:

- Give some of your tougher monsters a single legendary save, don't tell the players.
- In some cases, give charmed mouks advantage on social interactions, if warranted, balancing out the advantage the charmed condition gives. "Joe, what's wrong with you?! Everyone, look, Joe's gone over to the PCs!"
- The monsters don't have to ignore the Rod. Once it's been used, smarter ones can figure out what's happened. Really smart ones can try to take it away. Wouldn't that be fun?

#### RAW interpretation

###### 1. You have to present a convincing narrative on why you should be their leader to the targets when presenting the rod (similar to what suggestion demands)

- **Not RAW**

You present the rod and command obiedence. That means, you show them the rod. *Maybe* you have to actually say something, it's not an unreasonable reading that merely showing the rod is "commanding obiedence, no words necessary". But perhaps you have to say "Obey!"

Each target makes a saving throw. A target fails it, it regards you as its trusted leader. It makes it, you're some guy with a fancy stick.

###### 2. Attacking any member of the opposing group will break the charm on those that are charmed

- **Not RAW**

It says, "if harmed . . . a target ceases." It makes no mention if its buddies are harmed.

###### 3. Ordering charmed targets to attack their former allies will break the charm

- **RAW, but case by case basis**

If you order a target to attack its former allies, if that's "contrary to its nature", that breaks the charm. Up to the GM to decide contrariness.

###### 4. Commanding hostile, agressive creatures not to attack your companions will break the charm

**RAW, depends**

Assuming they're charmed, and its contrary to their nature not to attack your companions, yep, gonna break the charm.

Also, you don't really get to issue orders, they're really more like guidelines. The rod gives you advantage on social interactions, a command is a social interaction; you command, you make an ability check, maybe they do what you want, maybe they don't.

###### 5. You cannot charm creatures with the rod when already in combat or direct conflict

- **Not RAW**

You show the rod, they make the save. It says that.

Comment: Hehe, thanks Jack. Hard to have multiple encounters in a day for him if he throws the whole dungeon level at us, I guess :)

Comment: BTW, I scrolled over the "Don't Read It" part, and will pass it on

Comment: Ha ha.  That was just my attempt to be clever at suggesting some ways a GM can deal with the RoR.  But thanks for not reading. ;)

Answer (score 0):

### Sack your DM

When you are in an abusive relationship the best option is to leave.

Comment: At least I enjoy the challenge to still somehow make it and the high stakes fights. But we need to use all the tricks in the book, including convincing the DM that he's off the map when he is. Once he is not in the heat of combat any more (and sometimes if we scream at him enough, even in combat :)) he's open to listen to appeals to reason.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin I am an advocate of 'work with your GM/DM as a default' but Dale is seeing something that I am seeing, which is a bit of "DM versus Players" in approach by the DM. It's a style I have seen before, and it can sometimes get worse. Not sure if I agree with "sack him" but a conversation on DM vs Players may be needed.